# Angularjs keeps giving TypeError: Cannot read property 'dhx_security' of undefined

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm trying to get the dhtmlx event calendar to work on my angularjs webapp. I'm still new to all this, and combining the calendar with angularjs and php+mysql (to get events from db), there is not that much info to be found on the combination of those 3.

This code initialises the calendar:

```
    myAppProfile.directive('dhxScheduler', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    transclude: true,
    template:'<div class="dhx_cal_navline" ng-transclude></div><div class="dhx_cal_header"></div><div class="dhx_cal_data"></div>',

    link:function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller){
      //default state of the scheduler
      if (!$scope.scheduler)
        $scope.scheduler = {};
      $scope.scheduler.mode = $scope.scheduler.mode || "month";
      $scope.scheduler.date = $scope.scheduler.date || new Date();

      //watch data collection, reload on changes
      $scope.$watch($attrs.data, function(collection){
        scheduler.clearAll();
        scheduler.parse(collection, "json"); <-- UNDEFINED
      }, true);

      //watch mode and date
      $scope.$watch(function(){
        return $scope.scheduler.mode + $scope.scheduler.date.toString();
      }, function(nv, ov) {
        var mode = scheduler.getState();
        if (nv.date != mode.date || nv.mode != mode.mode)
          scheduler.setCurrentView($scope.scheduler.date, $scope.scheduler.mode);
      }, true);

      //size of scheduler
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        return $element[0].offsetWidth + "." + $element[0].offsetHeight;
      }, function() {
        scheduler.setCurrentView();
      });

      //styling for dhtmlx scheduler
      $element.addClass("dhx_cal_container");

      //init scheduler
      scheduler.init($element[0], new Date(), "month");
      scheduler.load("agendaController.php");
    }
  }
});
```

Where I put the arrow, there it keeps turning up undefined. Don't know why it is, I do load in correct json data at the end, but even if the calendar is empty it should still work. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that $watch triggers an event immediately after initialization before a value is assigned to the data attribute.

Try this:

```
$scope.$watch($attrs.data, function(collection){
  if(collection) {
    scheduler.clearAll();
    scheduler.parse(collection, "json");
  }
}, true);
```